# Проверить, работает ли отправка писем на сервере (php)

Tags: php, sendmail

Нужно, чтобы движок опредлял, можно ли отправлять почту с установленной машины. Каким образом можно проверить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

отправить почту на mailforspam.com допустим, и curl получить html если есть кодовое слово в письме то почта отправляеться. Ну и конечно же проверить возвращаемое значение функции mail если она изначально вернёт false значит письмо не отправленно.